# How to find & return all non-zero values within an unknown range?

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing, countif

```
=IF(ROWS(AA$38:AA38)>COUNTIF(U$38:U$1000,"<>0"),"",INDEX(U$38:U$1000,SMALL(IF(U$38:U$1000>0,ROW(U$38:U$1000)-ROW(U$38)+1),ROWS(AA$38:AA38))))
```

I'm trying to use this formula to find and return all the non-zero values in a column of data (starting from row 38), but I don't know how many rows there will be before I import the data. I'd like to be able to just automate the sorting, but if I use (`U:U`) or pick a much larger number than the actual number of filled rows (eg. `U$38:U$20000`), I get an error.

Is there a way of either:

a) getting excel to automatically change the (`U$38:U$####`) to the number of rows filled with data? (ie, if there are 400 rows, it would change to (`U$38:U$400`).)

OR

b) finding an alternative formula that can pick out all the non-zero values, without knowing the number of rows?

EDIT:

As you can see from the image below, I've set up my spreadsheet so that it not only returns the non-zero values (from column U), but also the time (from column AG) that it corresponds to. The problem is when I try to increase the range.

I'll be looking at lots of different data files with varying amounts of data, so I would like to be able to automate it - and not have to fiddle about with the all the `U$38:U$1000`'s every time I need to change the range. Does that make sense?

Is it possible with VBA instead?

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvtfm.png)

Comment: We can make the range dynamic, yes. In order to do so optimally, it would be useful to know the datatype of one of the ranges in your table: for example, are the entries in column U always numeric?

Comment: Yes, they are - but they might be positive or negative.

Comment: Are the entries all contiguous?  Or might there be empty cells in the column before the end?

Comment: Oh, and what do you want to do with these values?

Comment: No, there aren't any empty cells before the end.

Comment: I'd like to have them in another column, in exactly the same order as before, but without all the zeroes.

Comment: My Dynamic Range suggestion below is supposed to answer part a) of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in some column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($U:$U,SMALL(ROW(myRange)*(myRange<>0),SUMPRODUCT(N(myRange=0))+ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

Enter it in some cell. See that it returns the desired value, then fill down until it returns blanks.

`myRange` is some arbitrary range larger than your largest row size.  I used `u38:u20000`

[image]

**EDIT**:  To return values from a matching row in a different column than `U`, merely change the `array` argument in the `INDEX` function from `$U:$U` to the desired column,  eg:  `$AG:$AG`

**EDIT2:**  If you need to ignore error values in column `U`, try this <kbd>CSE</kbd> entered formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(U:U,SMALL(ROW(myRange)*(IFERROR(--myRange,0)<>0),SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(--myRange,0)=0))+ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Comment: I like the use of the N() function to cover blanks and zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I try this, it only returns blanks, and not the values I was expecting - was I just supposed to replace `myRange` with an arbitrary range?

Comment: @jm00548  Did you define `myRange`?  If you did not, it will return a `#NAME` error and hence the function will return a blank.  You need to set it to some range that refers, with absolute addressing, to a range larger than your expected.  eg.  `=Sheet1!$U$38:$U$20000`

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks.  Sometimes I use a double unary instead.  I don't know which is more efficient, though.  But there are fewer questions about the use of `N()` than about the use of `--`.  Also, if the blanks are spaces or text, then `N()` will still return zero whereas the double unary will return an error.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Do you mean replace every occurrence of `myRange` with `$U$38:$U$20000`?

Comment: @jm00548  Yes, or, more simply, you can just enter it as a `Defined Name`.  `Formulas` ribbon ► `Defined Name` tab ► `Define Name`:  Name:  `myRange`.  Scope: `Workbook`  Refers to: `=$U$38:$U$20000`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Thanks, I tried both defining the name and just replacing `myRange` with `$U$38:$U$20000`, but neither seems to have worked.

Comment: @jm00548  Hard to tell what you are doing incorrectly.  Are you certain you entered the formula by holding down `ctrl` + `shift` while you hit `enter`?  Did you copy/paste the formula exactly as I wrote it?  If you select the cell and examine the formula bar, do you see braces `{...}` around the formula as you should?

Comment: @jm00548 If you cannot figure out your issue, post a copy of your workbook, with sensitive information removed, to some sharing site and post a link here.  Also, with regard to your **Edit** and additional requirements, once you get this formula working, the change to return the result from a different column is trivial.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Yes, I copied your formula exactly and made sure to hold down `ctrl` and `shift`. Does it matter which cell it was used in?

Comment: @jm00548 It does not matter what cell it is in.  I did see your example, and, once the basic formula is working, the change to return the matching result from another column is trivial.  I'll need to see a copy of your workbook (sensitive info removed) in order to best help further.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I think I may have solved the problem - when I copy some of the data into a separate sheet, starting from Row 1 rather than Row 38, your formula works! (with `=$U$38:$U$20000` changed to `=$U$1:$U$20000`)

Comment: @jm00548 the original formula works fine in my workbook with the data starting at U38. I would really like to see what is going on in yours. There should be no reason to have to change the data location.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I think it must be because (like an idiot) I'd forgotten that I have some merged cells in the first few rows. Could this have affected it?

Comment: @jm00548  I just tried merging some cells in column `U`, both above and below U38.  It made no difference here.  But merged cells can cause problems in general.  For formatting, much better to select `center across selection` than merge, if possible.

Comment: @jm00548  Are you sure you didn't change the array argument in the INDEX function from `$U:$U` to a different range?  That would be one way to mess things up.  BTW, I posted an edit showing how to return values from other columns.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld No, it was definitely still `$U:$U`, but thanks very much for the **edit**!

Comment: @jm00548 well, if you have the time I'd sure like to see a copy of the problem worksheet. I'd like to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld The other explanation I thought of was that I noticed the Column U cells contained errors towards the end - changing those also fixed the problem. I'll try and upload a copy of the worksheet if I can, but it's a total mess of (embarrassingly awkward) formulas at the moment.

Comment: @jm00548 Yes, errors in the list will break the formula.  That is undoubtedly the reason.  Are you going to fix the errors?  Or do you need some other solution?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Yes, I've fixed it by adding `IFERROR` to my other formulas and now it works perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This a just a fix to the existing formula to make it work over a wider range, allow negative values and ignore empty cells, but (as I suspected) others may suggest more efficient solutions!

```
=IF(ROWS(AA$38:AA38)>COUNTIFS(U$38:U$10000,"<>0",U$38:U$10000,"<>"),"",INDEX(U$38:U$10000,SMALL(IF(U$38:U$10000<>0,ROW(U$38:U$10000)-ROW(U$38)+1),ROWS(AA$38:AA38))))
```

This can be made more efficient by declaring a dynamic range using Name Manager something like this:-

```
=Sheet1!$U$38:INDEX(Sheet1!$U$38:$U$10000,COUNT(Sheet1!$U$38:$U$10000))
```

and calling it (say) DynamicRange.

Then the formula becomes:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DynamicRange,SMALL(IF(DynamicRange<>0,ROW(DynamicRange )-ROW(INDEX( DynamicRange,1 ))+1 ),ROWS($1:1))),  "")
```

These are array formulae and must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I try this, it returns a `#DIV/0!` error.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce the #DIV/0! with my test data, maybe there are some issues with your real data as suggested by the exchange of comments between you and @Ron.