# Combining Non-Zero Values from Multiple Columns into One in Excel

Tags: excel

Every month I get given a budget from one of our clients in a Google sheet, which I need to convert into a SQL query so it can be uploaded into our database.  As the number of rows and columns changes, I want to write some formula to semi-automate the process for time saving and mistake elimination.

This budget has spends in multiple columns, which I've managed to write formulas to combine into one column, with the correct details in the columns next to it (see example links below).

*How I've transformed the data so far*

[image]

The issue is this budget per country and partner, then has to be split again across multiple options.  This leaves me with three columns worth of spend values, that I'd really like to combine back into one column, and ideally skip out all the zero values.

I've found an array formula on this site that will skip the zeroes, but I can't get it to work on more than one column.

=IFERROR(INDEX($U:$U,SMALL(ROW(myRange)*(myRange<>0),SUMPRODUCT(N(myRange=0))+ROWS($1:1))),"")

[From this Question's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657246/how-to-find-return-all-non-zero-values-within-an-unknown-range)

Is it possible to write a formula, that skips the zero values down one column, and then starts at the next?  And that will also allow me to keep the correct matching details from the other columns alongside it, as well as bring in the column headers for the options as entries in a new column?

Thanks

Edit:

[Here is the final format I'm looking for:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8jr.png)

There is a concatenated field off the end that combines all the columns.  Most of the values are populated by various Vlookups, to transform from the text version, into the database IDs, needed to fill the table.

It's also worth saying, that not being able to skip the zeros, is OK, as I can manually delete them fairly easily.

But as the number of countries and partners can and will change, I want the formula to be able to move column at the end of the dataset.

Comment: It might be possible to compose such a formula but it will surely be combersome to support. Is VBA out of the question? I've written similar code that removes rows with zero valued columns.

Comment: Have a look here: https://excelxor.com/2014/08/13/single-column-from-many-containing-blanks-1-rows-first/. The part <>"" in the main formula may  require changing to <>0 for your purposes.

Comment: Can you also share how your final data will look like.

Comment: I have no experience with VBA, so it's not out of the question, but would like to understand what I'm doing and how it works.

I've edited to include the final data set, and will have a look at that link.

Thanks for the help!